# if statement with OR in php

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

The following i have implemented but it doesnt make sense to me…can anyone help?

i wanted the following:

if monthsdue IS NOT EQUAL TO **one_month_due** *AND* payment is NOT BY **standing order** then{
    // do something
}

but to get it work i had to use the OR - see below

```
if(($monthsDue!=1) || ($Payment_Type!=STANDING_ORDER)){
    // send emails according to more criteria
}
```

For example 
if they are due one month but pay by cash or cheque then something should happen
if they are one month due and pay by standing order then nothing should happen
if they are 2 months due and pay by standing order something must happen.

I am pretty sure I am missing the obvious!

Comment: You wanted `AND` and you used `OR` (or `||`)?! What if you replace `||` with `&&`?

Comment: if (($monthsDue > 1) && ($Payment_Type !== "STANDING_ORDER) { // send emaills } Means if monthsdue is bigger then 1 month due and payment isn't equal to STANDING_ORDER

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to replace your || with &&.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(($monthsDue!=1) && ($Payment_Type!=STANDING_ORDER)){
    // send emails according to more criteria
}
```

**&& = AND, whereas || = OR.**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

However, if you use AND and OR, you'll eventually get tripped up by something like this:

```
$this = true;
$that = false;

$truthiness = $this and $that;
```

Want to guess what $truthiness equals?

If you said false... wrong!

**$truthiness above has the value true. Why? = has a higher precedence than and. The addition of parentheses to show the implicit order makes this clearer:**

```
($truthiness = $this) and $that
```

If you used && instead of and in the first code example, it would work as expected and be false.

Just something to be careful about!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this statement :

`if(($monthsDue!=1) || ($Payment_Type!=STANDING_ORDER))`

this means that "if monthsdue IS NOT EQUAL TO one_month_due **OR** payment is NOT BY standing order then{ // do something }"

But you need **AND** over there

so replace your OR operator(`||`) with AND operator(`&&`)

change it to

`if(($monthsDue!=1) && ($Payment_Type!=STANDING_ORDER))`